# Algolia Search and Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, vue.js, algolia

I am working on a search application that uses algolia for indexing. When the user types a search term into the text input box, we want to populate the autocompletion dropdown with events. Every event belongs to an event category as well.

Example:

```
{
  "category": "Disney",
  "events": [
    {
      "title": "Ice Skating"
    },
    {
      "title": "Peter-Pan"
    },
    {
      "title": "Roller Skating"
    }
  ]
}
```

If someone searches for "skating", we want to pull back the parent category and the child events "Ice Skating" and "Roller Skating" but omit the "Peter-Pan" event.

Is this type of nested filtering possible with Algolia? If so, how would the filtering work? Would it need to be done with JS, will Algolia handle it for me or do we need to create separate indexes for Event Categories and then Individual Events?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with algolia, but this section of their documentation may prove helpful: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Algolia will automatically filter out `Peter Pan` and return items with `Skating`.

As an example I've got some data setup like so:

```
announcements: [
  {
     id: ..,
     ..
     author: {
       id: ..,
       name: 'Preston',
       ..
     }
  },
  ..
]
```

If I search Announcements for `Preston` it'll return any announcement that has `Preston` in the `author` attribute. This is the default for Algolia and will search the entire record for your search term. This **can** be slow.

You can go into the Algolia dashboard, or with the [API](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/searchableAttributes/), and under your index's Ranking tab define what you want to search by and ignore.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is adding events.title to the searchable attributes. This will make sure that when the end-user types skat, it will match one of the title.

Then you can check what parts of each result is matched using [_highlightResult](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search-user-id/?language=javascript#method-response-_highlightresult-object) and more specifically filtering based on the [matchLevel](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search-synonyms/#method-response-matchlevel):

[image: checking the matchLevel in _highlightResult]

full is when you have a match and none is when you don't.

This filtering should be possible in JS, in the template you use to display the results.